# How to join two eloquent queries in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This is my attempt:

```
$calendar = Calendar::leftJoin("class", "class.start_date", "<=", "calendar.date")
        ->leftJoin("student", "class.id", "student.class_id")
        ->where("student.id", $id)
        ->select("calendar.date");
$calendarQuery = $calendar->toSql();

$temperature = Temperature
        ::leftJoin("temperature_type", "temperature.temperature_type_id", "temperature_type.id")
        ->where("temperature.student_id", $id)
        ->select("temperature.student_id", "temperature.id", DB::raw("date(temperature.created_at) as date"), DB::raw("cast(temperature.created_at as time) as time"), "status", "temperature_type_id", "temperature_type.name as temperature_type", "temperature.temperature", "temperature.unit")
        ->orderby("temperature.id");
$temperatureQuery = $temperature->toSql();

$return['output'] = DB::table(DB::raw("($temperatureQuery) AS temp"))
        ->rightJoin(DB::raw("($calendarQuery) AS cal"), 
        function($join) use ($calendar){
            $join->on("temp.date", "=" ,"cal.date")
            ->addBinding($calendar->getBindings());
        })->get();

return $return;
```

I would like to joining this two eloquent queries.

I found this problem. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answers?

Comment: Sry, i tried it but i didn't get the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fromSub()`:

```
DB::query()->fromSub($temperature, 'temp')
```

In Laravel 5.6.17 you can simplify the join with `rightJoinSub()`:

```
->rightJoinSub($calendar, 'cal', 'temp.date', 'cal.date')
```

Answer (score 0):

That occurs mainly because if you do dd($calendar), you will see that the toSql() method just translates the query into raw sql, without parameters. the $id will be '?' that's most likely it (as you can see on your bottom line of the error). The same applies to temperature

I don't advise converting to toSql() unless you really need to, you can do one single query to get the contents you're looking for